# Why are $\tfrac{5}{4}\pi + \tfrac{3}{2}\arctan(\tfrac{1}{2}) - \tfrac{3}{2}\arctan(2) - 2$ and $\arctan(2) + 4 \arctan(\tfrac{1}{2}) - 2$ equivalent?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Expression 1:

$\frac{5}{4}\pi + \frac{3}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) - \frac{3}{2}\arctan(2) - 2 \approx 0.961739$

Expression 2:

$\arctan(2) + 4\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) - 2 \approx 0.961739$

I encountered these two expressions by using different methods (trigonometry and calculus) to solve the same problem.
[Specifically, I found the area of the shaded region of this figure, where the side lengths of the square are 2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cMCI.png)

I'm quite certain that both answers are correct, but my question is: "how can I show that both of these expressions are equivalent?"

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: use the identity $\arctan(x)+\arctan(1/x)=\pi/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Remember the identity $arctan(x)+arctan(1/x)=π/2$

Start with Expression 2:

$\arctan(2)+ 4\arctan(\frac{1}{2})−2$

$= \arctan(2) + (\frac{5}{2}\arctan(\frac{1}{2})+\frac{3}{2}\arctan(\frac{1}{2}))−2$

The identity implies $arctan(1/2)=π/2 - arctan(2)$ so by substitution Expression 2 equals:

$\arctan(2) + \frac{5}{2}(\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan(2))+\frac{3}{2}\arctan(\frac{1}{2})−2 = \frac{5}{4}\pi + \frac{3}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) - \frac{3}{2}\arctan(2) - 2$

which is Expression 1, and so the two expressions are equivalent.

Thanks to *@Gonçalo* for reminding me of that arctan identity.

Answer (score 1):

It is equivalent to prove that $$
\begin{aligned}
& \frac{5}{4} \pi+\frac{3}{2} \arctan \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{3}{2} \arctan 2 =\arctan 2+4 \arctan \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Proof:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \arctan 2+4 \arctan\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{3}{2} \arctan \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{3}{2} \arctan 2 \\
 =&\frac{5}{2}\left(\arctan 2+\arctan \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right) \\
=&\frac{5}{2} \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} \\
=&\frac{5}{4}\pi
\end{aligned}
$$